# Javascript modify object in filter array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I need to filter. I am wondering if it is possible to modify the object in the filter function. I dont want to use .map then .filter because then it would loop thru the array twice making it take more time and wont scale if there are thousands of items in the list.

```
const cities = [
  {name: 'Los Angeles', population: 100},
  {name: 'New York', population: 80},
  {name: 'Chicago', population: 120},
  {name: 'Houston', population: 60},
  {name: 'Philadelphia', population: 70}
];

const highPopulation = cities.filter(item => {
  // item.isHighPopulation = true
  return item.population >= 100
});

console.log(highPopulation)
```

Maybe filter isnt the best solution to this problem. I just dont want multiple unessecary loops if I can do this operation in one loop.

Comment: Did you time how long it took to map then filter? I did this for 100k items and it took 10ms. For 1k items, it was less than 1ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const cities = [
  {name: 'Los Angeles', population: 100},
  {name: 'New York', population: 80},
  {name: 'Chicago', population: 120},
  {name: 'Houston', population: 60},
  {name: 'Philadelphia', population: 70}
];

const highPopulation = cities.reduce((items, item) => {
  if(item.population >= 100) items.push({...item, isHighPopulation: true});
  return items;
}, []);

console.log(highPopulation)
```

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const cities = [
  {name: 'Los Angeles', population: 100},
  {name: 'New York', population: 80},
  {name: 'Chicago', population: 120},
  {name: 'Houston', population: 60},
  {name: 'Philadelphia', population: 70}
];

const highPopulation = cities
  .filter(({ population }) => population >= 100)
  .map(item => ({...item, isHighPopulation: true}));

console.log(highPopulation)
```

Comment: Given that the OP cites performance and scalability as the reason to avoid the filter/map approach, I can't think the `reduce` approach could possibly be acceptable: it turns the `O(n)` operation into an `O(n²)` operation, creating and populating a new, larger array every time it encounters a high-population city.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior perhaps it's better to use ``Array#push`` here :) both solutions now are ``O(n)``

Comment: At that point, you're probably just better off using a for loop. filter/map/reduce should be used for non-mutating operations. Loops should be used for altering things. :-)

Comment: I didn't quite get your point, I'm not altering here, I'm creating new objects in a certain condition...

Comment: Your `reduce` lambda creates new objects, but it also uses `push` to alter the given array. Granted, the array is the one you create right there, so at least you're not messing with external objects. It just sort of breaks the functional paradigm. I really like your filter/map solution, btw.

Comment: So is reduce longer than the filter and map method? Im confused

Comment: @CryptoGeek981 both are good. I think that reduce do the job in one loop (``O(n)``) and filter/map do it in two (``O(2n)``). I suggest to try both and experiment which is faster for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is possible to modify the object in the filter function.

It is possible. The code you've posted would do what you're asking if you uncomment the commented line.

It is also a bad idea. Mutating objects in a transformation method like `filter` violates the command-query separation principle.

> I dont want to use .map then .filter

Hopefully you're not modifying objects in `map` either: you should be creating new objects instead. Something like `.map(item => {...item, isHighPopulation: item.population >= 100})`.

> because then it would loop thru the array twice making it take more time and wont scale if there are thousands of items in the list.

Have you tested this assumption? In my experience it's rare for something to take an acceptable amount of time to do `x` operations, but an unacceptable amount of time to do `2x` operations. If performance is an issue for you, it's probably better to take a broader look at your algorithms and data models. If not, you should probably not be worrying overmuch about it.

Answer (score 0):

With `forEach` loop, in one iteration and add items to results only on filter criteria

```js
const cities = [
  { name: "Los Angeles", population: 100 },
  { name: "New York", population: 80 },
  { name: "Chicago", population: 120 },
  { name: "Houston", population: 60 },
  { name: "Philadelphia", population: 70 },
];

const isHigh = ({ population }) => population >= 100;

const highPopulation = (arr, res = []) => {
  arr.forEach(
    (item) => isHigh(item) && res.push({ ...item, isHighPopulation: true })
  );
  return res;
};

console.log(highPopulation(cities));
```